# jQuery Chosen Plugin Insert Multiple data into database

Tags: php, jquery

I have problem with this :
Please visit http://s13.postimg.org/na4ppenfb/Stack.jpg
I use jQuery choosen. I have download that, from this address : http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/, but I have modified that. this my code, can anybody help my problem :

```
  <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
    <div><em>Dosen Pembimbing</em>
      <select data-placeholder="DOSEN PEMBIMBING KP" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" tabindex="5" id="dosen_pembimbing_kp" name="dosen_pembimbing_kp">
          <option disabled selected>PILIH DOSEN PEMBIMBING</option>
          <?php
             include('config.php');
             $query="SELECT * FROM dosen";
             $daftar=mysql_query($query);
             while ($dosen=mysql_fetch_object($daftar)) 
             {
                echo"<option>$dosen->nama</option>";
             }
             ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div><em>Mahasiswa</em>
      <select data-placeholder="Pilih Mahasiswa KP" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6" id="mhs" name="mhs">
        <option value=""></option>
          <?php
             include('config.php');
             $query="SELECT * FROM mahasiswa_kp";
             $daftar=mysql_query($query);
             while ($mhs=mysql_fetch_object($daftar)) 
             {
                echo"<option value='$mhs->nim_mhs_kp'>$mhs->nim_mhs_kp</option>";
             }
             ?>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="side-by-side clearfix">
      <p>&nbsp;          </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Simpan" />
        &nbsp;
        <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content padding ui-corner-all"/>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Please help me for insert data into database with PHP code.

Comment: i guess u need to write : echo"<option value='$dosen->nama'>$dosen->nama</option>"; in 1st select list

Comment: Thanks for your repair. 
I'm still a beginner learned about this business.
I still get an error when I try to create a code update, this is my jquery code [link](http://s5.postimg.org/84qa7xiyf/jquery.png) and this my code update  [link](http://s5.postimg.org/pgqmtdcfr/update.png) . I know this code is wrong, because in these cases there is some data are selected.
Can you help me fix it

Comment: where is form tag in ur code? if its already present then u just have to check print_r($_POST) on ur process page..so u will come to know whether all inputs are POSTing or not..

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've found the correct code. My first change in this code.
http://s5.postimg.org/96nnbj7zr/New_Code.png
then to update the code like this
http://s5.postimg.org/spwtymw53/New_Code_Update.png